# Nombre para un lugar donde se venden materiales de construcción

Tags: solicitud-de-término, sustantivos, sinónimos, construcción-y-obra

¿Hay otros nombres para un lugar donde se venden materiales de construcción específicamente? En mi país, Uruguay, se usa "barraca", pero si busco sinónimos encuentro viviendas, cuarteles militares o ferreterías.

La distinción entre una ferretería y una barraca es que la primera vende herramientas y no necesariamente materiales.

Comment: En España no he oído nunca nada más que _tienda de material para la construcción_, sin más.

Comment: En México lo que yo recuerdo es *casa de materiales*.  Se entiende por el contexto, o si no, entonces *casa de materiales de construcción*.

Comment: @fedorqui eso es que te faltan [zonas de España por visitar](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/30822/12637). :-)

Answer (score 5):

En Argentina un lugar donde se venden materiales de construcción se denomina ***corralón***. Para merecer ese nombre como mínimo (y quizá principalmente) debe vender arena, cal, cemento, etc., además de lo cual puede comercializar vigas o tirantes de metal o madera.

También se le llama *corralón* si además de estos materiales básicos ofrece revestimientos (cerámicos, mosaicos, etc.), cañerías, grifería, y hasta pinturería y electricidad, además de las herramientas asociadas a estos materiales e insumos, pero salvo que se trate de un negocio muy grande, lo habitual es encontrar estas cosas en establecimientos especializados diferentes.

Answer (score 2):

No te puedo dar una respuesta muy amplia, pero en Andalucía (o, al menos, en la zona de Sevilla y Cádiz), España, a un sitio donde se venden materiales de construcción se le llama ***polvero***.

No trates de buscarla en el diccionario, que no viene, pero en el *Vocabulario andaluz* de Alcalá Venceslada sí que se recoge, tal y como atestigua una [ficha](http://web.frl.es/FICHERO/FICHERO/LETRA_P/LETRA_P_PDF/POLVERO/00000578.pdf) (PDF) del *Fichero general* de la RAE:

> POLVERO.— m. Almacén de materiales de construcción. (Sevilla.)
>   "En el *polvero* de la calle Alhóndiga compré los materiales para la obra de mi casa."

Al parecer su uso comenzó en Sevilla y se acabó extendiendo a las provincias vecinas. También de uso muy limitado a la zona de la bahía de Cádiz es la voz ***calería***, que originalmente [significa](https://dle.rae.es/?id=6mTMw8p) "sitio donde se muele y vende la cal", pero que en la zona se usa por extensión para denominar al almacén de materiales de la construcción.

Answer (score 0):

En Cuba se usa *tienda de materiales de la construcción*

Comment: No creo que esto responda a la pregunta, ya que está pidiendo nombres específicos.

Comment: A mí me parece bien esta respuesta.  +1.  // Eduardo, quizás se recibirá mejor tu respuesta si incluyes un enlace a un sitio cubano donde se pueda ver el término en uso natural.  (A veces las respuestas súper cortas quedan rechazadas por el sóftware, por el solo hecho de ser cortas.) // Bienvenido al sitio.